# Many authors, multiple affiliations (à la revtex, without revtex)

Tags: automation, author, affiliation, authblk

I am trying to typeset a paper with a large number of authors and affiliations for a journal. In the file, there are authors with more than one affiliations and distinct authors with the same affiliation. A short example of that would be:

```
\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 2}
 
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation{Afiliation 3}
```

The preprint of it was typeset using the `revtex4-1` class. The journal that I am typesetting it for has its own class, based on `article`. The journal uses a primitive, manual way to typeset the authors and affiliations, like:

```
Author 1\textsuperscript{1,2} and
Author 2\textsuperscript{1,3}
[...]
\textsuperscript{1}~Affiliation 1
\textsuperscript{2}~Affiliation 2
\textsuperscript{3}~Affiliation 3
```

(yes, I don't like it either, but can't change that)

Due to the large number of authors and affiliations, it is inefficient to retype/copy-paste all the names and addresses, so I would like to use and/or tweak some package to do it for me.

I tried loading the `ltxfront` package, which is what `revtex4-1` uses for its frontmatter, but it results in a weird `Undefined control sequence. \end{document}`. I guess revtex people want people to use the whole class and not individual packages.

I also tried the `authblk` package with the option `noblocks`. This looked promising initially but it messes up with the numbering of affiliations. Namely, the output looks like the following picture:

[image]

I could do

```
\author[1,2]{Author 1}
\affiliation[1]{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation[2]{Affiliation 2}
 
\author[1,3]{Author 2}
\affiliation[1]{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation[3]{Afiliation 3}
```

instead, but it still doesn't combine the two instances of "Affiliation 1" plus, it is almost impossible to do this without errors for 143 distinct authors affiliated with 113 addresses in total.

The desired output would be something like:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using `authblk`? Or a way to achieve this in general?

For completeness a MWE is provided below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\newcommand{\affiliation}{\affil}


\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation{Affiliation 2}
 
\author{Author 2}
\affiliation{Affiliation 1}
\affiliation{Afiliation 3}

\title{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Finally, there are a few related questions but none of them achieves what I'm looking for.

**Extra (optional):** If someone's feeling extra spicy, I would like to include an extra superscript (e.g. have `Author 1\textsuperscript{1,$\star$}`) for a subset of the authors (in order to specify that they are the corresponding author(s)). I would appreciate it if that was included in the answer. This is optional, however. *I will be also satisfied with an answer not including this.*

Comment: Why don't you use `\author[1,2]{Author 1}\author[1,3]{Author 2}\affiliation[1]{Affiliation 1}\affiliation[2]{Affiliation 2}\affiliation[3]{Afiliation 3}`? Why do you repeat the first affiliation?

Comment: Because it's more than a hundred authors and more than a hundred affiliations and each of them just included their own name and affiliation(s). It would take me too much time to manually number all of them and find which affiliations have already been included.

Comment: ok but if you already have the list `\author{Author 1}\affiliation{Affiliation 1}\affiliation{Affiliation 2}`, `\author{Author 2}\affiliation{Affiliation 1}\affiliation{Afiliation 3}` and so on, you can easily transform it in the right format (see my first comment) using a Python script for instance?

Comment: Can you point me to such a script? I'm a total noob in python.

Comment: and another language?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only speak a few natural languages, (La)TeX, and maths

Comment: Well, good, now it is time to learn Python! :) You could also go with regular expressions or more basic "Find and Replace" instances. However, using a script to achieve what you have in mind seems a good approach. There might be a LateX-only solution but I do not know how...

Comment: good thing I'm getting paid by the hour then :))

Comment: Even with a script, you can still pretend it took you a lot of time to deal with the 143 authors and 113 affiliations... :)